# Randomize cell value from range Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, range, cell, google-sheets-formula

Trying to build a calendar for social media posts that generates a different type of posts from 100+ suggestions.

I found this similar function for excel but couldn't figure out an alternative for Google Sheets.
https://exceljet.net/formula/random-value-from-list-or-table

Comment: I'm pretty sure those three functions have the same name in Google Sheets. Can you please edit your answer and let us know what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

to replicate it try:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(ROW(A2), ROW(A6)))
```

[image: 0]